# Facing java.lang.ClassCastException while writing tests for a method that requires to map Object to List

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am writing unit-test for the below Class using Mockito:

```
public class ExternalQueryBuilder {

    public String buildQuery(Map<String, Object> request) {
        StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        if (request.containsKey("dataElement") && request.get("dataElement") != null) {
            queryBuilder.append("&Data Element=").append(request.get("dataElement"));
        }

        log.info(String.valueOf(request.get("dataSourceType")));

        if (request.containsKey("dataSourceType")) {
            List<String> dataSourceType = (List<String>) request.get("dataSourceType");
            if(dataSourceType.size() > 0)
                queryBuilder.append("&Data Source Type=").append(dataSourceType.get(0).replace("&", "\\&"));
        }
}
}
```

As you can see in this method, there is one line inside `if (request.containsKey("dataSourceType"))` which is `List<String> dataSourceType = (List<String>) request.get("dataSourceType");` doing this casting of whatever data coming from `request.get("dataSourceType");`. In this line I am getting this error `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class java.util.List (java.lang.Object and java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

Now my test code is:

```
    public void buildQueryTest(){
        StringBuilder queryBuilder = Mockito.mock(StringBuilder.class);
        Object obj = Mockito.mock(Object.class);
        Map<String, Object> request = new HashMap<>();
        request.put("dataElement",obj);
        request.put("dataSourceType",obj);
        externalQueryBuilder.buildQuery(request);
    }
```

In this code I am initialising `request` with type `Map<String, Object>` since in the above Class method that I m testing the type of `request` is `Map<String, Object>` only.

Then at the end I am calling the actual method `externalQueryBuilder.buildQuery(request);` where externalQueryBuilder is the object of the class I am mocking.This line will call the actual method and when I reach to line `List<String> dataSourceType = (List<String>) request.get("dataSourceType");` it throws the Classcast error in actual method.
I need some help with that. Please provide some suggestions to resolve it.I am new to both Java and Mockito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not assign object to list like

```
List<String> dataSourceType = (List<String>) request.get("dataSourceType");
```

assign it to object having list

```
Object obj = request.get("dataSourceType");
```

Object obj can be custom Object with List property which can be obtained as obj.getListProperty
check on feasibility of gettting list from obj

Comment: but then if I dont convert it to list, then this code part wont run correctly i guess `if(dataSourceType.size() > 0)
                queryBuilder.append("&Data Source Type=").append(dataSourceType.get(0).replace("&", "\\&"));` . Not sure, since its not my code, its written by someone else.

Comment: Object obj can be custom Object with List<String> property which can be obtained as obj.getListProperty